# Concatenate array to itself in order to duplicate it

Tags: javascript, arrays

In `Python`:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4] * 2 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What is the way to go with `JavaScript` ?

Currently using:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4];
data.concat(data);
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is. Are you asking what is the best practice?

Comment: @Ofiris please make clear your question.

Comment: @Gohn67, yes, was wondering if that is the way to go or there is more pleasant syntax, like the `Python` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't multiply arrays in JavaScript. Your current solution using [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is correct. 
Note that it creates a separate array with the copied items, and does not alter the original.

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary N, `array * N` can be written like this

```
[].concat.apply([], Array.apply(0, Array(N)).map(function() { return data }))
```

Of course, this sucks compared to the python version, but it's the best javascript can do. If you're looking for better syntax, try coffeescript.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 6, you can use [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
[].concat.apply([], Array(N).fill(array));
```

It can be simplified using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
[].concat(...Array(N).fill(array));
```

However, note that unlike `fill`, the spread operator can't be polyfilled.