# Fastest way to repeat an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have been trying to figure out a fast way of creating an array based on repeating an element a given number of times. For my purposes, generally the element I'd be repeating is another array, and I'd be making a long repeated (2-dimensional) array out of it, so I'd prefer it to be fast. Note that in each example, `c=[element]` since that's how it naturally occurs in my code.

There are a few options here that I've found. At most basic is option 1:

```
function repeatSimple(c, n) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    arr = arr.concat(c);
  };
  return arr;
};
```

Then from this question ([Concatenate array to itself in order to duplicate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597165/concatenate-array-to-itself-in-order-to-duplicate-it?rq=1)), gdbdmdb has another option:

```
function repeatApply(c, n) {
  return [].concat.apply([], Array.apply(0, Array(n)).map(function() { return c }));
};
```

My thinking was (a) I don't really understand the second option well enough to know whether it's a good solution, and (b) it seems silly to have to call `concat` a whopping `n` times as in the first option. So I came up with one more:

```
function repeatBinary(c, n) {
  var arr = [];
  var r = 0;
  while (n>0) {
    r = n%2;
    if (r>0) {
      arr = arr.concat(c);
    };
    n = (n-r)/2;
    if (n>0) {
      c = c.concat(c);
    };
  };
  return arr
};
```

This way, I only have to call `concat` at most 2log_2(`n`) times.

So, my question is, what is the fastest way to do this? Is it one of the options I'm looking at here or is there something else that blows them out of the water? Or will all of these options work at such similar speeds that it really doesn't make a difference?

Comment: I think this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ArtjomB. code review is for reviewing code for a *solved* problem

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I guess that depends on whether this code runs at all. Since the code doesn't seem to be final, I agree.

Comment: I think its dependant on the underlying js engine optimizations. It might optimize. Smaller concats might win if the engine can copy/ move array elements as contiguous memory blocks.

Comment: @ZigMandel I'm doing this in Google Apps Script for a Sheets project, so it's using their engine. By smaller concats, do you mean concatenating smaller arrays or smaller number of concat calls?

Comment: I mean less calls to concat. Haven't tried to compare against simply .push

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way to do this witout even using the `concat` function :

```
function repeatSimple(element, times)
{
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0;i<times;i++)
      result.push(element);
    return result;
}
```

And if you don't want to use the `push` function , you can assign the value directly to the item on the array like this

```
function repeatSimple(element, times)
{
    var result = Array(times);
    for(var i=0;i<times;i++)
      result[i] = element;
    return result;
}
```

Another clever way to do this is to join an array and split it like this

```
function repeatSimple(element, times)
{
    (result = Array(times).join("," + element).split(',')).shift()
    return result;
}
```

But this last function returns an array of strings, you have to convert every element to the type you need, but anyway, these functions may help you